# when i check for the auth user question can edit or delete make eager loading like this how can fix this?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eager-loading

```
@if(Auth::id() === $question->user_id)
 <div class="ml-auto">
  <a href="{{ route('questions.edit',$question->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Edit</a>
  <form action="{{ route('questions.destroy' , $question->id) }}" method="post" style="display: inline">
     @csrf
     @method('DELETE')
     <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure for delete')" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    @endif
```

[image]

The user hasmany questions but when i make check for the user allow to edit or delete the query make eager loading like this image how can fix this with no eager loading

Comment: Is your check in a loop?
If yes, then print Auth::id() from the loop into a variable, and add a variable to the check

Comment: Try replace `(Auth::id() === $question->user_id)` to `(Auth::id() == $question->user_id)`

Comment: i fix this (auth()->user()->id === $question->user_id)